# RetryTemplate is only Executing Once

Tags: java, spring

In the below method i am using the retry logic, what i am expecting for the first try it should fail, for the second one it's should successfully  save.

```
public Record saveRecord(Record Record) {
            try {
                return vcRetry.execute(
                        context -> {
                            System.out.println("Inside the Method");
                            if(context.getRetryCount()==0)
                            throw new RuntimeException("Something went wrong");
                            return RecordDao.save(Record);
                        });
```

The above method is executing only one time, i had done some debugging the vcRetry template properties are correct :
[image]

Please help why it's not coming back the second time ?

Answer (score 0):

I think, we retry for particular type of exceptions. Try below link,

https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.springframework.retry.policy.SimpleRetryPolicy

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code, it worked well. but you set **backOffPeriod** to **12** seconds. Maybe you should be more patient((12 seconds)) to get your second call.
Please change your backOffPeriod to 2 seconds and try again.

I coded your scenario as follows:

> **Create RetryTemplate**

```
@Configuration
public class Config {

@Bean
public RetryTemplate retryTemplate() {

    RetryTemplate retryTemplate = new RetryTemplate();

    //BackOff Policy
    FixedBackOffPolicy fixedBackOffPolicy = new FixedBackOffPolicy();
    fixedBackOffPolicy.setBackOffPeriod(2000l);
    retryTemplate.setBackOffPolicy(fixedBackOffPolicy);

    //Retry Policy
    SimpleRetryPolicy retryPolicy = new SimpleRetryPolicy();
    retryPolicy.setMaxAttempts(2);
    retryTemplate.setRetryPolicy(retryPolicy);

    return retryTemplate;

    }
}
```

> **Use retryTemplate in TestService**

```
@Service
public class TestService {

@Autowired
private RetryTemplate retryTemplate;

public String testService() {

    //Retryable
    String result = retryTemplate.execute(context -> {
        System.out.println("Inside the Method, Retry = " + context.getRetryCount());
        if (context.getRetryCount() == 0)
            throw new RuntimeException("Something went wrong");
        return "Successfully Completed";
    });

    //Result
    System.out.println("FINAL Result = " + result);
    return result;
  }
}
```

> **Result in console :**
>
> Inside the Method, Retry = 0
>
> Inside the Method, Retry = 1
>
> FINAL Result = Successfully Completed